# redirect everything after some folder path / using .htaccess on (Apache/2.4 Server)

Tags: .htaccess

http://sdfitness.4hilton.com/trainers/dummytext

I'm interested to redirect everything after the /, in this case the "dummytext", to the [trainers](http://sdfitness.4hilton.com/trainers) page.

Comment: So you want to simply get rid of anything after `trainers/` yeah?

Comment: Yes, anything after trainers/ should redirect to [/trainers](http://sdfitness.4hilton.com/trainers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule matches any URL starting with `trainers/` and 301 redirects it to just `trainers`, dropping everything that comes after, including any query string.

```
RewriteRule ^trainers/.+ trainers? [R=301,L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=c889e6a3-54cf-5e2f-b62d-bbdce6bea6bb